# How to add checkboxes dynamically using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, thymeleaf

I use Bootstrap and have a form with 2 textfields and 2 checkboxes. With an add-Button, I want to add (per click) an additional textfield with checkbox. Currently I'm using this JS:

```
$("#addButton").click(function () {

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
        .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    /*  TODO: patterns festlegen    */
    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div class="form-group label-floating">' +
        '<label class="control-label">Answer' + counter + '</label>' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control"/>' +
        '</div><div class="togglebutton"><label><input type="checkbox" checked="">Toggle is on</input></label></div>');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#AnswerGroup");


    counter++;
});
```

It adds successfully the textfield, but the checkbox isn't showing up, only the text "Toggle is on".

How can I solve this? I inserted the JS inside `$(document).ready(function () {`.

**EDIT** I think the CSS causes the problem. When I simply add `'</div><input type="checkbox" checked=""/></div>'`, it only shows the checkbox without UI. After adding the rest (like class="togglebutton", I see nothing.

Comment: I don't know if it is the problem, but the input of type checkbox do not have a value. Remove the </input> and close it directly. <input type="checkbox" checked="" />

Comment: Post your html too

Comment: Since the JS code alone works: https://jsfiddle.net/9ra8vyw5/ , I guess the CSS cause the problem, maybe it doesn't display checkbox inside label.

Comment: @user2181397 What do you suggest?

Comment: @Benjamin Schüller it doesnt make any difference :/

Comment: @progysm If i add it directly to the static html, it works. It only doesn't work with the JS

Comment: add your bootstrap codes too.

Answer (score 1):

The markup for your checkbox is not correct:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" checked="">Toggle is on</input></label>
```

should be

```
<label><input type="checkbox" checked="" />Toggle is on</label>
```

Comment: Sadly It didnt make any difference. If I put the code directly inside my static HTML, it is working. Just when I try to add it dynamically with JS, it's not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

May be because input tag has no closing pair.

Try

```
'<input type="checkbox" checked="">'
```

And it has to have "name" attribute

Comment: It doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Tested answer

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#addButton").click(function () {
    var counter = 2; //for sample
    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
        .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    /*  TODO: patterns festlegen    */
    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div class="form-group label-floating">' +
        '<label class="control-label">Answer' + counter + '</label>' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control"/>' +
        '</div><div class="togglebutton"><label><input type="checkbox" checked="">Toggle is on</input></label></div>');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#AnswerGroup");


    counter++;
});
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="addButton" value="hello"/>
    <div id="AnswerGroup">  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the use of $(document.createElement('div'))

Comment: In this case it will create a wrapper div with ID TextBoxDiv2

Comment: If I add the label with checkbox static to html, it's working. Just when I try to add it dynamically with JS, the checkboxes are not visible (just the label).

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of `$("#addButton").click(function () {` get in the habit of doing `$("#addButton").on('click', function () {`, you'll have more control of the event listener in the future.

Next, `var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);` should be `var newTextBoxDiv = $('<div/>').prop('id', 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);`.

Next it seems you are creating content `newTextBoxDiv` and then inserting content after it. I'm not sure you want to do that. I would think you would want to add content to the box you just made. Additionally, according to [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/), it accepts html as an argument. I believe you calling `.html()` afterward is just setting the inner HTML of `newTextBoxDiv` anyway.

As your question specifically; you should be able to create a checkbox with the following syntax:
`var checkbox = $('<input/>').attr('type', 'checkbox');`

To set it to checked (or unchecked) you use `.prop()` like this:
`checkbox.prop('checked', true); //checks the box.`

To set it as an HTML string (and [have it checked](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)) I believe you should use the following syntax:
`<input type="checkbox" checked>`

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
newTextBoxDiv.append(...)
```

instead of

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html(...)
```